# How to create a new virtual column as decimal (10,2)? MYSQL

Tags: c#, mysql

How to create a new virtual column as decimal (10,2)?

```
SELECT 
    Codigo, 
    Quantidade, 
    Preco_Compra, 
    Preco_Venda, 
    Sum(Quantidade * Preco_Compra) As Total_Compra DECIMAL(10,2),
    Sum(Quantidade * Preco_Venda) As Total_Venda DECIMAL(10,2),
    Sum(Quantidade * Preco_Venda) - Sum(Quantidade * Preco_Compra) As Total_Lucro DECIMAL(10,2) 
FROM 
    produtos_cadastrados 
Where 
    user = '" + usuario + "'";
```

Comment: Just remove ` DECIMAL(10,2)` and you're good

Comment: I need for format the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast the result as DECIMAL(10, 2).

```
SELECT
    Codigo,
    Quantidade,
    Preco_Compra,
    Preco_Venda,
    CAST(Sum(Quantidade * Preco_Compra) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) As Total_Compra,
    CAST(Sum(Quantidade * Preco_Venda) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) As Total_Venda,
    CAST(Sum(Quantidade * Preco_Venda) - Sum(Quantidade * Preco_Compra) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) As Total_Lucro
FROM
    produtos_cadastrados
Where
    user = "'" + usuario + "'";
```